# Get all paths in a rose tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following implementation of a rose tree:

```
data Rose a = Empty | Branch a [Rose a] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

So I wanna get all of the paths in the tree, what I have done so far is the following:

```
paths :: Rose a -> [[a]]
paths Empty = [[]]
paths (Branch n []) = [[n]]
paths (Branch n ns) = map ((:) n . concat . paths) ns
```

This is my tree

```
sample2:: Rose String
sample2 = Branch "/" [Branch "dir1" [Branch "file1" [Empty], Branch "dir3" [Empty]], Branch "dir2" [Branch "file2" [Empty], Branch "file3" [Empty]]]
```

And the output of paths sample2 is the following: `[["/","dir1","file1","dir1","dir3"],["/","dir2","file2","dir2","file3"]]`

But I want it to be :

```
[["/","dir1","file1"],["/", "dir1","dir3"],["/","dir2","file2"],["/", "dir2","file3"]]
```

How to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate the end product, not the `paths` of the individual childs, so:

```
paths :: Rose a -> [[a]]
paths Empty = [[]]
paths (Branch n []) = [[n]]
paths (Branch n ns) = concatMap (map (n :) . paths) ns
```

Comment: I have a following question - how I can get all the paths but in the following format:
["/dir1/file1", "/dir1/dir3", etc]

Comment: replace `(n :)` with `((n ++ "/")++)` and `paths (Branch n []) = [n]`. The signature is then `Rose String -> [String]`. This will make paths like `//dir1/file1`, since it will use the prepending slash, so likely then the root should have an empty string as label.

Comment: @Vanessa I suggest not doing that all as one function. Instead use the `paths` function you already have, to produce a list of lists. Then a separate function can convert each of those lists can convert to the single-string representation.

Answer (score 0):

```hs
paths :: Rose a -> [[a]]
paths Empty = [[]]
paths (Branch n ns) = map (n :) (concat $ map paths ns)
```